# Array communication: convert C doubles to chars, then java bytes to doubles

Tags: types, interface

I'm having trouble sending an array of doubles from a C application to a java application (over UDP).

At the moment I am casting my double data, like this

```
char* dataChars = (char*) dataDoubles;
int charsLen = sizeof(double)*doublesLen;
```

and sending this data over UDP to java, which gets a packet containing the correct number of java double entries (ie doubles seem to be the same size in both).

On the java side I recieve a byte[], then I am using:

```
ByteArray b = ByteArray.wrap(byteData);
for(...){
   doubleData[i] = b.getDouble();
}
```

When I send a packet with data defined in C as

```
double TEST_DATA[4] = {1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0};
```

In java I get, reliably

```
 3.03865E-319 3.16E-322 2.0553E-320 4.079E-320
```

It looks like the bits are getting scrambled, but I dont know what would correct this.

Comment: it seems like you need to make sure that the bytes are send and decoded in the correct endianness. Also, you might want to use and (unsigned char*)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Miky Denescu's, the following modifiation solves the problem:

```
doubleData[i] = b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN),getDouble();
```